# Performing same actions on multiple virtual machines

Tags: virtual-machine, devops

I would like to run several Virtual Machines on my computer and open them as separate windowed applications. Is it possible to perform same actions in all of the VM's ? By same actions I mean using one mouse and keyboard at once at all of VM's.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean ssh connection, I highly recommend [MobaXterm](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/).

You can send one command to many servers.

Hope that helps